# ARP request source mac is different than the ethernet source mac

Tags: networking, wireshark, arp

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaMbc.png) an image of an arp request that a packet capture file contained.

The ARP sender mac address is different than the Ethernet source mac address.
is that something that can actually occur?

(the arp source mac is also the mac of the router of the subnet)

also this is a part of my homework so it may be a mistake.

Comment: Possibly.  Do you have a Huawei wireless access point, by any chance?

Comment: Yes, it is a mobile device used as a wireless access point, also the source mac address in the arp request is the router's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing this behavior because your Huawei access point is acting as a bridge, proxying the arp request. In this arrangement, the source MAC in the ARP header is the actual request or and the source in the frame is the bridge, which will allow it to relay the response to the original source host.